# Android - Certificate Pinning with Retrofit 2.3 and OkHTTP

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, certificate-pinning

Hello dear developers,

I have the following Problem:

I´m using Certificate Pinning successfully since a few months now, with OkHTTP 3.6 and Retrofit 1.9.0.

Recently I updated the used Retrofit version to 2.3.0 and with this started using OkHttp 3.8. Since the updates the Certificate Pinning is no longer working on devices between AN 4.1 and AN 6.0.

I tried using different OkHTTP versions but had no luck. Furthermore I tried to enforce the usage of a specific OkHTTP Version via gradle, but that didn´t change anything.

Here the code we use for Pinning:

```
public CertificatePinner provideCertificatePinner(@PinForDomain(DEUTSCHE_POST) final PinnedDomain deutschePost, @PinForDomain(NOVOMIND) final PinnedDomain novomindPin, @PinForDomain(EMMI) final PinnedDomain emmiPin) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating CertificatePinner");
    final CertificatePinner.Builder builder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();
    builder.add("www.url.com", "sha256Key");
    return builder.build();
}

public OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(CertificatePinner pinner) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating OkHttpClient");
    final OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
    clientBuilder.certificatePinner(provideCertificatePinner);
    clientBuilder.connectTimeout(BuildConfig.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    clientBuilder.writeTimeout(BuildConfig.WRITE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    clientBuilder.readTimeout(BuildConfig.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    return clientBuilder.build();
}
```

So I tried the following things:

Forcing the usage of TLS v1.2

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)  
.tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
.cipherSuites(
      CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
      CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
.build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder() 
    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
    .build();
```

And implementing a custom SSLSocketFactory forcing the usage of TLS v1.2 in Version under AN 4.1 according to: :https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372

**EDIT:**

For clarification. The Pining is not working means that I´m able to intercept the connection between my App and the Backend Server => 'Man in the middle'.

Right now I´m completely lost on how to fix this Issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Cheers 
Pascal

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "the Certificate Pinning is no longer working" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry I forgot that, added it right now. Thanks!

Comment: Create a reproducible test project and file an issue with the OkHttp folks, explaining how you are doing the MITM attack (Charles, etc.), I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the Problem was not caused by OKHTTP / Retrofit, but by a misconfiguration on client side. Being fairly new in that project I didn´t know all of it.

Sorry to have bothered you and thanks for any help given

Comment: what was the issue?i am experiencing same.